# Supercap maximum current rating

Tags: maximum-ratings, supercapacitor, capacitor-charging

I'm designing the power circuit for the \$V_{BAT}\$ portion of an STM32 microcontroller, using a supercap to hold the charge when the main is off.

I was calculating which resistor I should charge the supercap through, but I stumbled on the  specifications:

[image: Supercap specifications]

What is the meaning of the **MAX current at 30 min.** column ? It does not seem to be the absolute maximum rating.

The capacitor charging current will drop exponentially, but I don't know from these specifications if it can withstand 150mA for 10-20 seconds when charging the capacitor from 0V.

The capacitor case is can-like with a diameter of ~17mm, and the specs does not specify power ratings for the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can withstand 150mA for 10-20 seconds when charging the capacitor from 0V

It cannot. Maximum voltage is 5,5 volts, and its ESR is 65 Ohms => max current is about 85 mA.

> What is the meaning of the MAX current at 30 min. column ?

The [datasheet](http://www.kemet.com/Lists/ProductCatalog/Attachments/463/KEM_S6013_FG.pdf) has the answer: It is the residual current after 30 min. charging time (from completely discharged).